# Getting genre and adding to hast table of array of link list

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, hashmap, hashtable

I'm trying to load movie file and then find out the genres of the movies. Basically if the movie genre is different then each genre will be placed in a position in the link list. for example if i have

Action Drama Comedy each action movie will be placed in a array of link list with so if movie is action its placed under action. Have to do this by finding out the hash code of genre.

This is the `HashMap` class:

```
    public class HashMap<KeyType,DataType>
    {
    private int count;
    private int size;
    private List<HashEntry<KeyType,DataType>> [] table;

    public HashMap() {
    }

    public HashMap(int num)
    {
        size = num;
        table = new List[num];
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
            table[i] = new List<HashEntry<KeyType,DataType>>();
        }
    }

    public void insert(KeyType key, DataType data){
        if(key != null && data != null){
            int hash = key.hashCode() % size;
            HashEntry<KeyType, DataType> obj = new HashEntry(key, data);
            table[hash].append(obj);
            count++;
        }
    }

    public void display(){
      for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
          System.out.println("tables" + i + " ");
          table[i].display();
      }
    }

    public DataType find(KeyType key){
        int hash = key.hashCode()% size;
        List<HashEntry<KeyType,DataType>> list = table[hash];
        ListIterator <HashEntry<KeyType, DataType>> iter = list.getIterator();

        while(iter.isValid()){
            if(iter.item().getKey().equals(key)){
                return iter.item().getData();
            }
            iter.advance();
        }
        return null;
    }

   public void remove(KeyType key){
        int hash = key.hashCode() % size;
        List<HashEntry<KeyType,DataType>> list = table[hash];
        ListIterator <HashEntry<KeyType, DataType>> iter = list.getIterator();

        while(iter.isValid()){
            if(iter.item().getKey().equals(key)){
                list.remove(iter);
            }
            iter.advance();
        }
    }
```

And this is the `LoadingMovies` class I'm working on:

```
private static final int size = 100;
private static HashMap<String, List<Movies>> movieGenres = new HashMap<String,List<Movies>>(size);

public static void loadMovies(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String split = ","; //split with comma

    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));

    //ArrayList<Movies> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
    String wordIn;
    Movies movie = new Movies();

    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        wordIn = in.nextLine();
        String splitter[] = wordIn.split(split);

        String movieTitle = splitter[0];
        String movieGenre = splitter[1];
        String ageRating = splitter[2];
        double scoreRating = Double.parseDouble(splitter[3]);

        movie.setTitle(movieTitle);
        movie.setGenre(movieGenre);
        movie.setAgeRating(ageRating);
        movie.setScoreRating(scoreRating);

        List<Movies> moviesInThisGenre = movieGenres.find(movie.getGenre());
        if (moviesInThisGenre == null) {
            moviesInThisGenre = new List<>();
            movieGenres.insert(movie.getGenre(), moviesInThisGenre);
        }
        ListIterator<Movies> iter = moviesInThisGenre.getIterator();
        moviesInThisGenre.add(iter, movie);

    }
    movieGenres.display();
}
```

when i run this i get this and it points to my find method in the hashmap class:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -72
at TheMoviePackage.HashMap.find(HashMap.java:53)
at TheMoviePackage.LoadingMovies.loadMovies(LoadingMovies.java:50)
at TheMoviePackage.LoadingMovies.main(LoadingMovies.java:66)
```

Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)

What am i doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to use your own types, i think your hashcode is negative so it gives you negative array index, add Math.abs on index and it should be fine.

Comment: i cant use hash map from java.util im currently studying data structure so i need to know how to do this

Comment: when i use that i get this: `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: TheMoviePackage.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map
 at TheMoviePackage.LoadingMovies.<clinit>(LoadingMovies.java:25)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1`